# Unable to create date with current time from string

Tags: c#, date, datetime, telerik, telerik-datepicker

I am taking selected date from telerik date picker and want to take that selected date and current system time by 24 hours format and want date like this:

For Ex: `Current Date = dd/mm/yy HH:Minutes:Seconds`

```
21/1/2016 14:48:21
```

This is my code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//Error:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value= {1/21/2016 12:00:00 AM} 
Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString()=1/21/2016
```

**Error**:**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime on** `Datetime.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your format in the `ParseExact` from

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

to

```
"M/d/yyyy" or "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt" //the first one use .ToShortDateString(), the second one for 1/21/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

The first one only takes care for case like `21/12/1997`

The second one takes care `12/21/1997`, `2/21/1997`, `12/2/1997`, and `2/1/1997` in addition to take care of time info

Also, note that you may consider to have multiple formats (just in case): `"d/M/yyyy H:m:s"`, `"d/M/yyyy h:m:s tt"` to take care of the case where day and month are swapped and when you have `AM/PM`.

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I want ddate/Month/Year as date format and you havent consider machines cultures

Comment: @Learning In that case, then swap the day and month. And the culture needs to be settled by `CultureInfo`. But since you use `Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString()`, then `"M/d/yyyy"` or `"d/M/yyyy"` for the `DateTime.ParseExact` would do.

Comment: i have tried this but still getting same error:DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), "d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);

Comment: @Learning check your `string` correctly in the debug mode, and then strictly follow the format of the `string`. Otherwise, use multiple formats as I suggested.

Comment: i have checked in debug mode and getting the same date as i have specified in my question

Comment: You mean `Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString()=1/21/2016`? and then you use `"M/d/yyyy"` and still get the same error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101246/discussion-between-learning-and-ian).

Answer (score 1):

```
@yourDateTime.FormattedReviewDate.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy")
```

You might even just add a simple property to dateTime for the formatted display:

```
public string FormattedReviewDate
{
    get { return ReviewDate.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy"); } 
}
```

Note: Give your needed format

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse *anything*.

Your `Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value` is *already* `DateTime`, just assign this value to your `dt` variable.

```
DateTime dt = Datepicker1.SelectedDate.Value;
```

If you want to get it's string representation based on your format, just use `ToString` method with proper format.

```
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

which returns `21/1/2016 14:48:21` as a `string`.

Also if you want `1/21/2016` as a string, just change your format to `M/dd/yyyy` like;

```
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: i was expecting answer from you because when i was searching for this issue i have find your answer and have read it too and it was really good with good explaination and after reading it only i have manage to understand something about this culture

Comment: @Learning Culture setting applies the rules that when you parsing a string to DateTime or generate string representation of a DateTime.

Comment: Actually the problem is my system date time is in month/date format and i am specifying date/month format that is why it is giving error